# Keras LSTM different input output shape

Tags: python, keras, lstm

In my binary multilabel sequence classification problem, I have 22 timesteps in each input sentence. Now that I have added 200 dimensions of word embedding to each timestep, so my current input shape is `(*number of input sentence*,22,200)`. My output shape would be `(*number of input sentence*,4)`, `eg.[1,0,0,1]`.

My first question is, how to build the Keras LSTM model to accept 3D input and output 2D results. The following code outputs the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_41 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (7339, 4)
```

My second question is, when I add `TimeDistributed` layer, should I set the number of Dense layer to the number of features in input, in my case, that is `200`?

.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(padded_docs2, new_y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

start = datetime.datetime.now()
print(start)

# define the model
model = Sequential()
e = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size2, input_length=22, output_dim=200, weights=[embedding_matrix2], trainable=False)
model.add(e)
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],200),dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(200)))

model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1],activation='sigmoid'))

# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
# summarize the model
print(model.summary())

# fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=300, verbose=0)

end = datetime.datetime.now()
print(end)
print('Time taken to build the model: ', end-start)
```

Please let me know if I have missed out any information, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your model's `Lstm` layers gets 3D sequence and produces outputs of 3D. The same goes to `TimeDistributed` layer. If you want lstm to return 2D tensor the argument `return_sequences` should be false. Now you don't have to use `TimeDistributed` Wrapper. With this setup your model would be

```
model = Sequential()
e = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size2, input_length=22, output_dim=200, weights=[embedding_matrix2], trainable=False)
model.add(e)
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],200),dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(200))

model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1],activation='sigmoid'))
```

###Edit:
[TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) applies a given layer to each temporal slices of inputs.In your case for example, the temporal dimension is `X_train.shape[1]`. Let's assume `X_train.shape[1] == 10` and consider the following line.

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(200)))
```

Here the `TimeDistributed` wrapper creates one dense layer(Dense(200)) for each temporal slices(total of 10 dense layers). So for each temporal dimension you will get output with shape(batch_size, 200) and the final output tensor would have shape of (batch_size, 10, 200). But you said you want 2D output. So the `TimeDistributed` wouldn't work to get 2D from 3D inputs.
The other case is if you remove `TimeDistributed` wrapper and use only dense, like this.
model.add(Dense(200))
Then the dense layer first flatten the input to have shape (batch_size * 10, 200) and computes the dot product of fully connected layer. After dot product the dense layer reshapes the outputs to have the same shape as inputs. In your case (batch_size, 10, 200) and it is still 3D tensor.
But if you don't want to change the lstm layer you can replace `TimeDistributed` layer with another lstm layer with `return_sequences` set to false. Now your model would look like this.

```
model = Sequential()
e = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size2, input_length=22, output_dim=200, weights=[embedding_matrix2], trainable=False)
model.add(e)
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],200),dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],200),dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=False))

model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1],activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm working on your code. But may I know why TimeDistributed wrapper is not required here? What is the actual purpose of TimeDistributed layer, would you kindly explain based on my problem? @Mitiku

Comment: `TimeDistributed` is used when you want to have an **additional** time dimension in your data. (But LSTMs are made to work with a time dimension already, you don't need an additional). In fact, all that `TimeDistributed` does is to make the layers inside it ignore the dimension of index 1.

Comment: @DanielMöller thanks for your clear answer. I'm newbie to deep learning, can you provide some good links for keras LSTM examples? Would appreciate alot

Comment: @Mitiku I've tried your solution, but the model predicts the same probabilities for each test set, do you know what's the problem?

Comment: What about training loss and training accuracy? If the model is performing well on training dataset and performing worse on test case then there are three possibilities.  1. The model is over-fitted and does not have ability to generalize to unseen examples. 2. Distribution the test sets drawn from is  different than distribution training sets are drawn. 3. There is some problem with your data pre-processing.

Comment: What if the input shape is (number of rows * 22 * 200) and output shape should be (number of rows * 3 * 10)? Basically trying to predict 3 variables which can range from 0 to 9.